# Query for the top 10 most used tags in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

Each `Topic` has a list of `Tags`:

```
enum Visibility {
  Public,
  Private
}

class Topic {
  public Visibility Visibility {get;set;}
  public List<string> Tags {get;set;}
}
```

I want to get the most used tags: `{"Math", 10}, {"Programming", 3}` but only for *public* topics.
Without filter, it's trivial (automatic index is created):

```
session.Query<Topic>()
            .GroupByArrayValues(t => t.Tags)
            .Select(grouping => new { Count = grouping.Count(), Text = grouping.Key })
            .OrderByDescending(grouping => grouping.Count)
            .ToList()
```

As I understand I need to include `Visibility` into grouping key, but I can't figure out exact syntax for that.